# Cant connect Cloudant with DSX

Tags: cloudant, data-science-experience

Im trying to connect de DSX(Data science experience) from IBM with a Cloundant NoSQL instance.

I try to use the host for that connection and it gave me the "Connection null" error.

After that, i used the url and it gave me this error:

```
"The repository operation was unsuccessful and returned this error: 
 CDICW9028E: An Internal Server Error occurred when interacting with the 
 Asset API. Contact IBM software support. The message received from the Asset API was: {"trace":"781951097","errors":[{"code":"ReservedValue","message":"500 Internal Server Error at https:\/\/dlprod.cloudant.com:443\/yp_prod_v2_admin\/_design\/adminSearch_v11\/_search\/adminSearch?include_docs=true&q=((buckets.container_id:%2259796e0a-166c-4a06-a139-e93962bdb774%22%20AND%20buckets.bucket_state:%22active%22))%20AND%20api_version:2.0%20AND%20state:active. Error: unknown_error. Reason: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@\/srv\/search_index\/shards\/b0000000-bfffffff\/dlprod\/yp_prod_v2_admin.1496892012\/b1a2ff5f4f7be3032ee60b318f779d53\/write.lock."}]}."
```

Comment: You should report that to IBM Support via the chat box on the bottom right on DSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran into a server-side problem:
https://console.bluemix.net/status/notification/6c488828c319132833c713dbc4ce911b

Please try again.